# Using ADO to run sql script (with GO syntax) in inno setup

Tags: pascal-script

I am using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260493/how-to-connect-to-ms-sql-server-using-innosetup) to run my sql scripts in inno setup. However ADO gives an error if the script contains GO syntax within it. I added my own code to overcome this problem.

My code below splits the script at each GO statement and run each section separately. I think this could be done in better ways.

```
[code]
const
 adCmdText = $00000001;
 adExecuteNoRecords = $00000080;

procedure RunScript();
var
 tString: TStringList;
 ADOCommand: Variant;
 ADORecordset: Variant;
 ADOConnection: Variant;  
 i, len: Integer;
 strToQuery, str: String;
begin
 try
 ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection'); 
 ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 
  'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +               // provider
  'Data Source=(local)\SQL2000;' +   // server name
  'Initial Catalog=databasename;' +       // default database
  'User Id=userId;' +                // user name
  'Password=password;';                   // password
 ADOConnection.Open;
 try
  ADOCommand := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
  ADOCommand.ActiveConnection := ADOConnection;
   tString:= TStringList.Create;
   tString.LoadFromFile('C:\sqlscript.sql');
   len:= tString.Count;
   strToQuery:='';
   for i:=0 to len-1 do begin
    str := trim(tString[i]);          
    if POS('go', lowercase(str)) = 1  then begin
     //If GO is found run the script added in to strToQuery since last GO
     ADOCommand.CommandText := strToQuery;                           
     ADOCommand.Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText or adExecuteNoRecords);
     strToQuery:='';        //Clear the string to start adding till next GO
     end else strToQuery:= strToQuery +#13#10+ str;  //Add the script to strToQuery
    end;
    ADOCommand.CommandText := strToQuery;                           
    ADOCommand.Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText or adExecuteNoRecords);
 finally
  ADOConnection.Close;
  tString.Free;
 end;
 except
  MsgBox(GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
 end;
end;
```

Any suggestion to update the code will be much appreciated.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @Malachi, it's Pascal Script from [`Inno Setup`](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Comment: I wish there was a better tag that we could put on this question. @TLama, should it have an SQL tag?

Comment: @Malachi, I would keep it as it is. Although it's about parsing SQL script, it's related more to that Pascal Script than SQL language itself.

Comment: @TLama, I agree. I had to create that pascal-script tag. maybe it will take off and people will be using it a lot, and this question will get the attention it deserves

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***1. Function block***

Standalone action like loading a script from file and splitting it into SQL commands by the `GO` command, I would move into a separate function. That function might have the following prototype:

```
function LoadScriptFromFile(const FileName: string; out CommandList: TStrings): Integer;
begin

end;
```

Having such function will isolate parsing and execution parts of the script. You would first load the script from a file and then in the other part of the script iterate the parsed commands and execute each one.

***2. Object finalization***

Always try to encose object finalization into a separate `try..finally` block. In your code it applies to the `tString` object. This part:

```
ADOConnection.Open;
try
  tString := TStringList.Create;
  ...
finally
  ADOConnection.Close;
  tString.Free;
end;
```

Should become:

```
ADOConnection.Open;
try
  tString := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ...
  finally
    tString.Free;
  end;
finally
  ADOConnection.Close;
end;
```

***3. Useless variable***

The `len` variable is used for only one purpose and its value is used only once, so it's actually useless there. I would remove it and write directly:

```
for i := 0 to tString.Count - 1 do
begin
  ...
end;
```

***4. Summary***

Except the above (not so major) things I would say your code is fine. The string concatenation with line breaks you have used should be fine for ADO connected to the SQL Server, I think.

For the sake of completness, here is what I'd write (untested!). <strike>Please note, that every SQL command is expected to be "terminated" by the `GO` command in the input file (that requires also your original code)</strike>:

```
function LoadScriptFromFile(const FileName: string; out CommandList: TStrings): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  SQLCommand: string;
  ScriptFile: TStringList;
begin
  Result := 0;
  ScriptFile := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SQLCommand := '';
    ScriptFile.LoadFromFile(FileName);

    for I := 0 to ScriptFile.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if Pos('go', LowerCase(Trim(ScriptFile[I]))) = 1 then
      begin
        Result := Result + 1;
        CommandList.Add(SQLCommand);
        SQLCommand := '';
      end
      else
        SQLCommand := SQLCommand + ScriptFile[I] + #13#10;
    end;

    //EDIT: If there is no GO syntax present int the file AND
    //To add the script after the last GO - Govs
    CommandList.Add(SQLCommand);
    Result:= Result + 1;
  finally
    ScriptFile.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure RunScript(const FileName: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  CommandList: TStrings;
  ...
begin
  ...
  // here is already established connection
  CommandList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if LoadScriptFromFile(FileName, CommandList) > 0 then
      for I := 0 to CommandList.Count - 1 do
      begin
        // execute each command
        ADOCommand.CommandText := CommandList[I];
        ADOCommand.Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText or adExecuteNoRecords);
      end;
  finally
    CommandList.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: I guess Inc() function is not supported in Inno.

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't even tried to compile my version (hence my note "untested"). I just wanted to show you my thoughts ;-)

Comment: Yes I understand. Just for reference if any body want to use the code. :)

Comment: Updated the function LoadScriptFromFile(). The script after last GO was not getting added. Also it will work if the script does not contain any GO syntax.

Comment: Updated your update... I've mentioned that each command must have been terminated by `GO`, which no longer applies with your update.

Comment: @TLama Your input would be appreciated on [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/pascal-delphi-pascal-script-tags) regarding the Pascal/Pascal-Script/Delphi tags we have here on Code Review.